# AppHarbor with NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, appharbor

Has anyone had any luck getting NServiceBus going on AppHarbor?

It doesn't look like there is any support for MSMQ. Are there alternatives that would work well for AppHarbor?

Comment: Any infrastructure that you use could be a problem in a shared hosting environment :) --- one typically has access to some version of sql server.  I do not know if NSB has a transport for sql server but if not it may be worth investigating how to create one.

Comment: The soon-to-be-released v4 has a transport for SQL Server, yes. It also supports RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ (among others).

Comment: It says not to use v4 in a production environment on the homepage